# What is known about "overlapping" models/minors of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors, planar-graphs, graph-cut

Suppose we are given a graph $G$ from a graph class of sublinear treewidth and connected subgraphs $G_1,G_2,..,G_l$ of $G$ such that each $G_i$ intersects (shares a node with) constant many other $G_j$ on average.

Construct a graph $H$ on $l$ nodes $h_1,h_2,..,h_l$ where $h_i h_j$ is an edge iff there is an edge from $G_i$ to $G_j$ or $G_i$ intersects $G_j$.

What sparsity properties are possessed by $H$?  For instance does $H$ have a sublinear separator? i.e. a set $S$ of $O(\sqrt(l)$ vertices such that each component of $H \backslash S$ has size at most $2l/3$?

Does H have an r-division?  a set $S$ of size  $O(l/\sqrt(r) $ such that each component of $H \backslash S$ has size at most $r$?

What about if $G_i$ intersects a constant number of other $G_j$ on average?